# Whiat is the difference between identity provdier and resident identity provider in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can not understand the difference between identity provdier and resident identity provider.

Following blog(http://blog.facilelogin.com/2014/10/wso2-identity-server-500-resident.html) said that "If you are a service provider and wants to send an authentication request or a provisioning request to the Identity Server 
(say, via SAML, OpenID, OpenID Connect, SCIM, WS-Trust) - what matters for you is the resident identity provider configuration.".

Identity Provider provide Federated Authenticators which has OpenID, SAML, Facebook and etc configuration.
But, resident identity provider also provide Inbound Authentication Configuration which it provides OpenID, SAML2, OAuth and WS-Trust configuration.

Of course, i know that resident identity provider's Inbound Authenticator just provide metadata (simple url and so on). But identity provider's Federated Authenticator have many option. 
Because same configuration is existing, read only the WSO2 IS document or blog, i don't know the need of resident identity provider.

I want to know the difference and actual example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it would be simple. Same as `Resident Service Provider`. WSO2IS also would acts a Identity Provider. Basically as a SAML2 SSO IDP, OpenID, OAuth2 Authorization Server and so on.  Then configurations that are related  them,  can be found at `Resident Identity Provider`.  As an example,  if you take WSO2IS as SAML2 SSO IDP. Think, about the configurations  that are related to the SAML2 SSO IDP.  One thing is that,  IDP url, issuer name and etc. There must be some place that we can configure those. `Resident Identity Provider` provide some UI configuration for it.  However, `Resident Identity Provider` configuration does not contain all the configurations that are needed.  But it provides some important/few configs. If you need to find out more configurations that are related to SAML2 IDP,  you can find them in the `identity.xml` configuration file. `identity.xml`  file contains the all the configuration that are related to the  Identity Provider.